# Will mesibo solution ( VDO & Audio) API will work in Oman & also mesibo SDk compatible with iconic framework?

Tags: mesibo

Will mesibo solution ( VDO & Audio) API will work in Oman & also mesibo SDk compatible with iconic framework ?

Comment: helpfull? https://mesibo.com/documentation/install/cross-platform-tools/

Answer (score 0):

We have tried it in UAE and it works.

Regarding ionic, refer this https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/#does-mesibo-supports-cross-platform-tools-like-flutter-react-native-ionic-etc

> You can use mesibo with all the cross-platform tools like Flutter, React-Native, Ionic, etc. mesibo APIs are provided as a Native SDK for Android, iOS, and Web. Since all the cross-platform tools offer a way to access native APIs, you can use mesibo from the platform of your choice. Refer to respective platform documentation to learn how to access native APIs. You can also refer a short tutorial here Using mesibo with Cross-Platform Application Development Tools like Flutter, React-Native, Swift, Ionic, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. What about Oman ? UAE & Oman both have different rules and regulations?

Comment: I have no idea. Why don't you write a small app and find it out if it works in Oman? 

You can download sample source code here  https://github.com/mesibo/samples